# Adding a dimension to a SQL Server cube inflates all measures

Tags: ssas, dimensions, measure

I have a SSAS cube that has worked fine for a while. I recently added a new dimension and now all the measures are vastly inflated. For instance, a count that should be about 300,000 for the whole model (i.e. with no filters at all) is now 1,500,000. All the measures I have checked are affected. The measure values are always way too high, but not be any consistent factor (i.e. some are 5 times too big, others 10 or 20 times too big). The errors are present whether or not the new dimension is included in the query.

I went back to a previously working version and tried again, making sure that the only changes I made were:

- Add a new table in the dsv
- Create a new dimension based on that table and add it to the cube
- Define referenced relationships in the dimension usage matrix to link the new dimension to the measures via one of the other existing dimensions

My caution didn't pay off -- the second attempt gave the same result as the first, which points to a conceptual or design problem. Any ideas where I might look for my mistake?

## More Details

The cube structure is as follows, with the recently added Church table highlighted:

[image: Cube structure]

The cube has many measure groups, but since all seem to be adversely affected by the introduction of this new dimension, I'll focus on just the one labeled "cm". We are a charity organisation that raises money for children in poverty around the world. "cm" represents a financial commitment that a supporter ("con" means "constituent") makes to child in need. Analysing the number of commitments by various con attributes has worked fine for a long time. We can also successfully analyse cm's by attributes in constituent_address via a referenced relationship.

Since most of our constituents belong to a church of some form, we wanted to add church details to the cube (e.g. church name, church size, denomination). We could then, for instance, count the number of commitments made by constituents who belong to Baptist churches. I added the Church table, and modified the con named query to include a church_id. (I also checked that the new con query returns exactly the same number of records as the old one, so I don't think the ensuing problem is caused by the con table changing.)

Here's an extract of the dimension usage matrix:

[image: Dimension usage]

And here is a before and after example. The first shows the correct count of commitments before the Church dimension was added. The second shows the same measure, built from exactly the same data, with the only changes to the cube being the addition of the Church dim. As you'll see, the new Church dimension is not explicitly included in the query but the measure now shows a commitment count of 1,574,823 rather than 315,057.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

--Matt

Comment: I have never experienced such a thing in SSAS, without Some schema pictures with new dimension, count measure before and after dimension picture it's hard to say anything.

Comment: I agree with @Justin. If you could post some more info, that would be helpful. We definitely need to see the dimension usage for your new dimension.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest. I have added more details and screenshots to the main description now.

Comment: Another observation: when I run the named query behind the cm table, there are only 1,260,300 records in total. Since the measure Commitment Count is a simple "count of non-empty values" of the cm primary key, I find it hard to grasp how the cube can show a measure value any greater than 1,260,300 *regardless* of what is defined in any dimension.

Comment: Could it be that adding the new dimension blows up the number of records of the result from joining constituent and church, as compared to constituent alone? E. e. that the join by `Organisation Id` and `Church Id` is not a manny-to-one relationship from constituent to church, but in your data there is more than one church entry for some constituents?

Comment: @FrankPl - that's a good suggestion. I can see how that could result in the symptoms I am seeing. I will investigate later to day.

Comment: The join between con and church looks right to me.  * The con named query returns 552,720 records both before and after the changes: the new version simply appends a `Church ID` field.  * That `Church ID` field is often null and sometimes contains an ID that does not exist in the church table (that's a data quality issue I need to fix but I can't see how it could cause he current problem).  * In the church table `Organisation ID` is unique, so the join with `con.[Church ID] = church.[Organisation ID]` is properly many-to-one.

Comment: I have now chickened out by giving up on the separate church dimension. Instead, I have included the various church attributes in the constituent dim. This is less neat from a user point of view and introduces plenty of data redundancy, but it works.